# How to remove br tag inside contenteditable using Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an event to remove all `br` tags when user adds some text to the editor.

I've tried with this code but it just works fine on Chrome. When I use Firefox to test it, the code removes the space inside the text.

```js
$('div').on('input', function () {
  $(this).find('br').remove();
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

This is what's happen when I typed `s s s s s` (contains space) using Firefox browser:

https://i.ibb.co/s2DL0Nb/Untitled.png

Comment: Different browsers [generate differences markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#Differences_in_markup_generation) in contenteditable. Firefox generate `<br>` on enter press and your code removing `<br>`

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry, the link you provided doesn't contain solution that how to fix the problem.